# Web Slideshow automated

Tags: javascript, php, image, slideshow

I have a computer with Xibo on (digital signage-program), and it´s a little tricky to add more then just one picture at the same time. So I have an idéa about doing a slideshow on a website. That way I can show the website instead of using the built-in-slideshow.

I've made a website where I can upload pictures to and fill in dates that tells the slideshowwebsite between wich dates the picture will be displayed. And I can also type in how long the individual pciture will be displayed. This is saved in
a database along with the path and filename.

But I'm going nowhere with the slideshow-Webside. I've looked a bit on Javascript, but I can not choose individual time for the picture. I want to be able to determine this
myself when I upload the picture.

This site is supposed to automatically recreate itselfs every day to get rid of old pictures and in with the new. What I had intended to do with a bash-script..

Grateful forall the help I can get!

Regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

Cool question and this sort of thing is exactly what PHP was built for - dynamically displaying HTML to the browser based on certain criteria.

So it sounds like you have the database INSERT and UPDATE portions settled. I do recommend that you use timestamps rather than dates. It also makes it easier to handle queries in MySQL for finding specific dates since timestamps are integers and can be sorted as such. To get a timestamp you can use the time() expression in PHP to get the current time or you can use strtotime the timestamp for a specific date. For example:

```
$newDate = strtotime("March 3, 2014"); //$newDate is now a timestamp for that date rather than plain text
```

strtotime is flexible and can handle other date types, including numbers with dashes like 12/14/2013.

But anyway, once you have that settled, you need to work on your SELECT queries for the front-end display.

It'll look something like this:

```
$now = time();
$html = '';
$pull = mysql_query("SELECT imageurl,width,height,time FROM banners WHERE bannerstart <= '$now' AND bannerend <= '$now'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pull)){
    $html .= "<img src='" . $row['imageurl'] . "' />"; //build the rest of your HTML here too and echo it to the page below
}
if($html == ''){
   echo "No images right now. Please check back later!";
}else{
    echo $html;
}
```

If you're looking into banners that fade from one to the next like you see in large multi-media displays, I recommend [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

Comment: Thanks! Great help! But how do I make it to change picture?:S Sorry for the noobquestion..

Comment: If you're asking about making it change between several pictures on a page like you see on other sites, then the Cycle2 code does that for you. At the most basic level, you put a list of images onto a page and Cycle hides all but one and then animates through the list slowly, fading or sliding from one to the next.

If you are asking about changing images from day to day, it would happen based on the dates you enter at the point of creation for when the image should be "live".

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still valid, 
may be following slideshow maker api can be some help
https://github.com/picovico/php-sdk